# issue with getting shipping details in Google checkout (Magento)

Tags: magento

I ve been trying integrating Google checkout with my Magento website.
I have configured Google merchant id and api key in the Magento backend, i could able to see a
Google checkout in my shopping cart.

But after the redirection, i could only see the product order details.
My shipping rates are not showing up in Google checkout screen.

I am using both Flat rate and a custom "Shipping rate" calculated based on category of the product. (I wrote a custom shipping module for this)

Below screen shows the configuration i made in Mage backend and shipping methods in shopping cart

[image]

and

[image]

What am i doing wrong? or do i have to write any customization to get the shipping details to GC?

**Note : Google Checkout Shipping Carrier calulated and Flat rate is disabled in Magento Backend.**

thanks,
Balan

Comment: Just clarifying - do you mean the shipping costs you are sending aren't being displayed *after* the user logs in (or creates a Google acct)? If so, can you actually see the data that you are sending to Google Checkout?

Comment: Yup.. i can see actual products in GC.. 
but after some research i found that GC will call back Magento to get the shipping calculation... this is the reason i am not getting actual shipping value..

Comment: I'm **not** a Magento user - that means its implementing [Merchant Calculations API](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Merchant_Calculations_API.html) so you'll have to enable that and ensure it responds within 3 seconds to Google's request - otherwise Google will use the default value (you also set).

Comment: Yes.. i got this.. trying to fix this..